# Why in Kibana 4 , it is showing "You must choose and item from the list" in the Field section of Data visualisations page?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I have an elasticsearch index which I am using to index a set of documents.

These documents are originally in csv format and I am looking parse these using logstash.

In Kibana 4 Visualisation page, (See Attached Image below)

In the Field " Current Device Installs" , after I press apply, a Pop up is coming that "You must choose an item from the list".

[image: Data Visualisation Page]

My logstash config file is,

```
        input {
        file {
                path => "/csv_files_for_logstash/app1lg.csv"
                        type => "core2"
                        start_position => "beginning"
        }   }


    filter {
        csv {
                separator => ","
                        columns=> ["Date","Package Name","App Version Code","Current Device Installs","Daily Device Installs","Daily Device Uninstalls","Daily Device Upgrades","Current User Installs","Total User Installs","Daily User Installs","Daily User Uninstalls"]
        }
        mutate {convert => ["App Version Code", "string"]}
        mutate {convert => ["Current Device Installs", "float"]}
        mutate {convert => ["Daily Device Installs", "float"]}
        mutate {convert => ["Daily Device Uninstalls", "float"]}
        mutate {convert => ["Current User Installs", "float"]}
        mutate {convert => ["Total User Installs", "float"]}
        mutate {convert => ["Daily User Installs", "float"]}
        mutate {convert => ["Daily User Uninstalls", "float"]}
        ruby {
                code => '
                  b = event["App Version Code"]
                  string2=""
                  for counter in (3..(b.size-1))
                         if counter == 4
                                 string2+= "."+ b[counter]
                         elsif counter ==  6
                                string2+= "("+b[counter]
                         elsif counter == 8
                                string2+= b[counter] + ")"
                         else
                                 string2+= b[counter]
                         end

                   end

                   event["App Version Code"] = string2

                  '

        }
}
   output {
        elasticsearch {
                embedded => true
                        action => "index"
                        host => "es"
                        index => "fivetry"
                        workers => 1

        }
        stdout{
                codec => rubydebug {
                }
        }
}
```

What will be the possible reason for this bug and how can I remove this?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only Max count of the field Current Device Installs, you can click on X (Cross) Button in the section Split Rows & click on Apply.

In this case it will output the Maximum count of Current Device Installs field.